# Issue with htaccess file for website

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm running a website and have encountered indexing problems on google. Mainly because I use links based on php identifiers like `?go=7`

Now I created a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tubes/([*]+)\.html$ index.php?tubeID=$1 [L]
```

I also tried a different regex:

```
^tubes/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$
```

The file itself is working, since when I put an error in it, the site crash. A try with this script/instructions worked [https://docs.bolt.cm](https://docs.bolt.cm/3.4/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works)

I'm really stuck. Any help on this?

Comment: What is not working? Do you have any example of URL that should be working?

Comment: The rewrite is not working. Yes: http://swissnixie.com/index.php?tubeID=3400005

Comment: But your rewrite won't grab that URL. Your patter is looking for: `swissnixie.com/tubes/some-string.html`. You've seem to have gotten it backwards. The first part RewriteRule is the pattern it should match on. The second part is the URL it _internally_ uses when calling your app. A common misconception is also that rewrites rewrite the actual URL in the browser, which it doesn't. It just maps one pattern to a URL "under the hood".

Comment: google is well use to urls with arguments, i doubt this is really an issue.

Comment: So this tutorial is totally crap? https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ ... the example in "Patterns and replacements" looks very similar to my issue

Comment: I concur with 'rtfm' ... while GET is acceptable in URLs, there are reasons to believe that Google *favors* not having them. However, it's not a huge issue; if you're not found on Google at all, start by giving them a sitemap (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en)

Comment: I get found and have a sitmap, but the indexer marks the sites with the ids als "duplicates", and only indexes like 8 pages out of  250

Comment: I think the point of the tutorial is that a URL like this:

www.example.com/tubes/wang-lab/340-0005.html

Is more descriptive than this:

www.example.com/index.php?tubeID=3400005

Making what used to be called SEF (Search engine friendly) urls is a common practice.

Comment: well that would indicate the issue is with the content of the page, not the url

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
RewriteRule ^tubes\/([^\/]+)\.html?$ index.php?tubeID=$1 [L]
```

This will capture all URLs that matches like the following:

```
http://example.com/tubes/34000005.html
http://example.com/tubes/my-video-id.html
```

### Explanation

```
tubes\/  Make sure the url starts with tubes/
([^\/]+) Capture everything that is not a slash (/)
```

### Update

To redirect the other way around, add the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tubeID=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/tubes/%1.html [R=302,L]
```

This will redirect `http://example.com/index.php?tubeID=10` to `http://example.com/tbues/10.html`

Comment: I tried that, but it does not work... Is it possible that i get the whole idea wrong? I want to get "index.php?tubeID=1" to become ".com/tubes/"id"/ not other way around

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^tubes/(.*)\.html$ index.php?tubeID=$1 [L]
```

And then, the URL you want to go to would be like this:

```
http://swissnixie.com/tubes/34000005.html
```

Comment: Though, I'd note, I noticed that your images are in a folder named "tubes", which just so happens to be the same name of the rewrite rule that you're trying to use.  This can sometimes cause issues if you're not careful.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i will change it. But the code you posted does not change my issue :/

Comment: It's going to take more code to actually CONVERT the incoming url to match the flat .html url.  That's not what the rewrite rule does.

Comment: A rule like that would be something more like this (this is off the top of my head and not tested)
RewriteRule ^index\.php?tubeID=(.*)$ http://example.com/tubes/$1.html [L,R=301]